# How to implement joins inside sub-query referring tables in main query in SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, join, sql-server-2000

I have a following query which has joins in sub-queries and joined table is referred from the main query from clause. This is SQL Server 2000 syntax, I am trying to migrate it to 2008 syntax but I get an error at runtime. Please suggest.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PRODUCT]
(
        [pid] [int] NULL,
        [NAME] [nchar](10) NULL,
        [PDID] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PRODUCTDESC]
(
        [PDID] [int] NULL,
        [DESC] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

--Test Data
insert into PRODUCT values (1,'ONE',1);
insert into PRODUCT values (2,'2',2);
insert into PRODUCT values (3,'3',2);
insert into PRODUCT values (4,'4',null);
insert into PRODUCT values (5,'4',5);

INSERT INTO PRODUCTDESC VALUES (1,'ONENEN');
INSERT INTO PRODUCTDESC VALUES (2,'TWEONEN');

-- SQL Server 2000
SELECT 
    Name,
    (SELECT [DESC]
     FROM PRODUCTDESC
     WHERE PRODUCT.PDID *= PRODUCTDESC.PDID)
FROM   
    PRODUCT 

--RESULTS
/*
    Name    (No column name)
    ONE         ONENEN    
    2           TWEONEN   
    3           TWEONEN   
    4           NULL
    */

-- SQL Server 2008
SELECT 
    NAME,
    (SELECT [DESC]
     FROM PRODUCT
     LEFT OUTER JOIN PRODUCTDESC ON PRODUCT.PDID = PRODUCTDESC.PDID)
FROM   
    PRODUCT 

--RESULTS
/*
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
*/
```

In the above 2008 query with in sub query how can we access the TABLES referred in main query form clause, so that I don't get sub query returend more than 1 value error

Please suggest.

Comment: sqlnewbie: You are not at liberty to simply delete the content of everyone else's post, please stop suggesting edits of this nature. I am rolling back your question once more so it contains the content that everyone here answered.

Comment: @wesley - I rolled it back again

Comment: sqlnewbie, edits are for clarification, spelling, grammar, punctuation, formatting, etc. - I'm not sure what you had in mind but I don't think anyone will appreciate you erasing the answer that they took the time to provide to you.

Comment: @Wesley - rejected.  I also flagged for mod attention.

Comment: @sqlnewbie: If your question needs clarification, then clarify it. But do not just delete the question text; that's not going to work. If you have a new question, ask it using the "Ask a Question" button.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT PRODUCT.NAME
       ,PRODUCTDESC.[DESC]
FROM   PRODUCT
LEFT JOIN PRODUCTDESC
    ON PRODUCT.PDID = PRODUCTDESC.PDID
```

Note that the problem is because you have a scalar subquery, which MUST return only a single row (or no row).  Note that this means that the original query with that data would fail in SQL Server 2000 as well.  In addition, in both SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2008R2 and all version in between, the left join *= operator is not even necessary:

```
DECLARE @PRODUCT TABLE (
    [PDID] [int] NULL,
    [NAME] [nchar](10) NULL
)

DECLARE @PRODUCTDESC TABLE (
    [PDID] [int] NULL,
    [DESC] [nchar](10) NULL
)

--Test Data
insert into @PRODUCT values (1,'ONE');
insert into @PRODUCT values (2,'2');
insert into @PRODUCT values (3,'3');
insert into @PRODUCT values (4,'4');

INSERT INTO @PRODUCTDESC VALUES (1,'ONENEN');
INSERT INTO @PRODUCTDESC VALUES (2,'TWEONEN');


--SQL 2000-2008R2
SELECT Name,
       (SELECT [DESC]
        FROM   @PRODUCTDESC AS PRODUCTDESC
        WHERE  PRODUCT.PDID = PRODUCTDESC.PDID)
FROM   @PRODUCT AS PRODUCT
```

Comment: thank you, yes that would fetch me the result, but i am looking for an alternative on how we can access outer query tables within joins of sub-queries defined in select clause

Comment: @Srinivas - your error is because of the subquery not being able to be used as a scalar.  You can use an outer value in a subquery as you have.  In your case, because you are using PRODUCT twice, you need to alias the outer one so that it isn't hidden by the inner one.  I believe your first query would fail in SQL Server 2000 with the same issue because of the subquery needs to return only one row when used as a scalar.

Comment: i have tried the original query in SQL 2000 compatibility mode and it fetched the result set correctly...

Comment: @Cade-- what i am thinking is in SQL 2000 query the sub-query uses the results from the outer-query and applies a join with that result set with the tables defined in sub-query....i am wondering how can we bring this feature in 2008

Comment: You should not under any circumstances even in SQL server 2000 be using an implicit left join. It is broken even in SQL server 2000 and is not guaranteed to return the correct results. For 2008, you need to replace all code using this immediately. This is deprecated code, it will **not** be available in the next version of SQl Server at all. Fixing this should be a a critical task.

Comment: Next correlated subqueries are a SQL antipattern. Again they should almost never be used as they are performance killers. @Cade Roux suggested a better method for doing this. If you need only one record you could create a derived table or CTE to pick the max or min record from the table for each PDID.) You need to learn to write code that correctly uses joins not correlated subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do?

```
select p.Name,pdesc.DESC, from PRODUCT p inner join PRODUCTDESC pdesc on pdesc.PDID=p.PDID
```

Comment: thank you, yes that would fetch me the result, but i am looking for an alternative on how we can access outer query tables within joins of sub-queries defined in select clause.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the outer join in your sub query. This will work just fine.

```
SELECT Name,
       (SELECT [DESC]
        FROM   PRODUCTDESC
        WHERE  PRODUCT.PDID = PRODUCTDESC.PDID)
FROM   PRODUCT
```